# Does event source mapping get deleted along with the lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda and have created an event source mapping for the same. When I delete the lambda using Python boto3, does the event source mapping also get deleted along with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  A Lambda [Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) is a separate, customer-managed resource.  It has its own [CRUD API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) and CloudFormation [AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html) resource type.  You must delete it yourself with `delete_event_source_mapping`.

```py
res = client.list_event_source_mappings(EventSourceArn=queue_arn, FunctionName=function_name)
assert len(res["EventSourceMappings"]) == 1

client.delete_function(FunctionName=function_name)

res = client.list_event_source_mappings(EventSourceArn=queue_arn, FunctionName=function_name)
assert len(res["EventSourceMappings"]) == 1

client.delete_event_source_mapping(UUID=mapping_uuid)

res = client.list_event_source_mappings(EventSourceArn=queue_arn, FunctionName=function_name)
assert len(res["EventSourceMappings"]) == 0 # wait a few seconds for deletion to finish
```